# iTunes movies HD Rental advertised as 5.1 surround, but only plays in stereo

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

"The Revenant" is clearly labeled on the iTunes store as 5.1 surround. But after purchasing and playing the HD Rental (yes it was fully buffered) it only output in stereo on Windows 10.

The Netflix app outputs 5.1 surround correctly, and so do games, and so do 5.1 surround sound music downloads played through VLC, so I know my set up is correct.

Am I missing a setting? Also, can I get a refund?

Answer (score 1):

This is a long-term issue for Windows 10.  I've seen problems with all 5.1 sound going back 18 months.  Most posts I've seen say to try this:

- Go to your **Windows Sounds** settings
- Under **Playback**, select **Speakers** and go to their **Properties**
- Under **Enhancements**, deselect the `Disable all enhancements` checkbox
- Activate the `Enable Speaker Fill` checkbox and click **Ok**

If that doesn't work, try this:

- Go to the sound settings
- Select your device
- `Properties => Advanced` tab then select **24bit, 96000Hz** from the dropdown

Comment: `Enable Speaker Fill` does create the 5.1 effect, but this is synthesized. Netflix app will play it natively with out virtualization.

Comment: Jonathan is right, filling the speakers is not surround sound.

Comment: @Jonathan I didn't say it was surround sound; only that similar posts have provided this direction.